# Pycharm, git: merge from master into branch

Tags: git, merge, pycharm, branch

I have a master branch `master` and I've made some changes & commits into a branch called `rmurphy`.  I found something that needs to change in `master` and want to

1. Make a change in `master`
2. Propagate the changes to branch `rmurphy` as well
3. Avoid overwriting the new stuff in branch `rmurphy` with the old stuff in `master`.  (note there will not be a conflict)
4. Do it in PyCharm.

The last one is important:I want to learn learn how to work with this IDE to better communicate with my team.

About a week ago, my colleague explained that I would want to "merge master into branch" in this situation.  (Unfortunately, this colleague will not be available for some time).  But neither that terminology or other variants lead to helpful Google search results.  Moreover, I have not found this use-case in my searching through forums and SO.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybbe this helps? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html

Answer (score 2):

1. After you have made the change in `master`, checkout `rmurphy`.
2. - If you haven't already pushed `rmurphy` to remote

     `Git Branches (widget) -> master -> Rebase Current onto Selected`
   - Else

     `Git Branches -> master -> Merge into Current`

For more merge settings use `VCS -> Git -> Merge Changes.../Rebase...`.

If you don't want to bother, you can always merge instead of rebasing.